# ¿Why are the distance vertical to the line and not perpendicular to the line?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-regression

I've been diving more into linear algebra recently, but there is something I can't get my head around when using least squares via linear algebra.

Having a plane, we have a line $a$, a point $b$ and a point $p$ which is the projection from $b$ to the line $a$. Also $p$ is the  closest distance from $b$ to $a$. The error will be the distance $b-p$ so: $ e = b - p $. We consider $a^Te=0$ (perpendicular). So $a^T(b-xa)=0$ and in matrix form $A^T(b-Ax)=0$ which leads to $A^TAx=A^Tb$.

[image: (fit)]

If I'm using the closest projection (perpendicular) to the "line":

¿Why are the vertical distances minimised and not the perpendicular to the line when resolving $A^TAx=A^Tb$?

¿Is there a way to know that before using these equations?

Thank you.

Comment: If this relates to regression, the reason is because when we use the output for regression as a model, the errors (residuals) are the difference between the true y-value and the y-value for the line, or in other words, the vertical distance.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I understand what are you saying, but I can't grasp the connection between the perpendicular projection and the vertical errors, because the error I described are the ones perpendicular to $a$ but not vertical errors.